# jQuery current regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like to assign a regular expression with the following format.

- 10
- 10.00
- 100.45

This can go *upto 10 digits*, followed by a *. (dot)* and *2 decimals*. I tried something like this,

```js
$(document).on("keypress", "#Amount", function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^\d{1,10}(\.\d{2})?$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

The above script is not allowing me to type anything in the text box.

but it didn't work.

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lag7gu7k/

Comment: The problem is that you should be checking the value of the box, not the key that was pressed.

Comment: @Yass: Have a look at [my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/56whu2xe/). Does it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that works.

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to implement two things:

- restrict live input so that a user could onlytype the numbers Iin the desired format
- perform final validation of the user input.

Regexes for live and final input validation should be different and they must be used on different events.

See [the JS demo](https://jsfiddle.net/56whu2xe/) showing how you can achieve that.

For live validation, on keypress event, use

```
var regex = /^\d{0,10}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/;
```

For final validation, on, say, blur event, use

```
var regex = /^\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{2})?$/;
```

## UPDATE

I enhanced the demo to allow more complex scenarios:

- It won't allow typing `.` before the 3rd and more characters from the end
- It should allow deleting the input by selecting the value with a mouse and typing another digit.

```js
var regex_final = /^\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{2})?$/;
var regex = /^\d{0,10}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/;
var last_input_char = '';
$(document).on("keypress", "#Amount", function (e) {
   last_input_char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
   var containsDecimalPoint = /\./.test($(this).val());
   if (containsDecimalPoint && /\.[^.]*\./.test($(this).val() + last_input_char)) {
       return false;
   } else {
     var sel_idx = $(this).getCursorPosition();
     var real_new_value = $(this).val().splice(sel_idx, 0, last_input_char);
     var pass = regex.test(real_new_value);
     return (e.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(last_input_char) || 
            /\./.test(last_input_char) && !containsDecimalPoint) && pass;
   }
});

$(document).on("blur", "#Amount", function (e) {
   var isValidAsPerRx = regex_final.test($(this).val());
   if (!isValidAsPerRx) {
      $('#Amount').removeClass("right");
     $('#Amount').addClass( "wrong" );
   } else {
      $('#Amount').addClass( "right" );
      $('#Amount').removeClass("wrong");
   }
});

// Adding the string.insert function
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

// Adding the function to get caret position
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.right {
    background: white;
    color: black;
  }
  .wrong {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="Amount" /><br/><span id="Error"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: i have noticed an issue with this solution. After user enters initial value, if user want to enter something else with selecting all text in the textbox then they have to use delete button. Is there way to enter values second time  without using delete button?

Comment: Do you mean after typing `12345.67` you want to place the cursor between `2` and `3`, type `9`, and the number will turn to `12945.67`? Please provide the details.

Comment: First you type 1234.56 then select all the numbers in the textbox using mouse and try to type any other valid number.

Comment: I revised the demo code. I did not think you were going to use my demo at all, I assumed you have a working code. Note I am not that sure this will work great with all browsers, I just collected some examples on SO and joined them into one solution. Feel free to test more, and leave more feedback if something is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{1,10}(\.\d{2})?$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/xX2qN5/2)

The idea is:

- `^$` - from the start til the end of the string
- `\d{1,10}` - one to ten digits
- `\.\d{2}` - followed by a dot and two digits
- `()?` - which are optional

Comment: thank you,  this is what i have in my code, but it didn't work. text box is not allowing me type anything

  $(document).on("keypress", "#Amount", function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^\d{1,10}(\.\d{2})?$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

Comment: @Yass, please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and link it in your question.

Comment: `var regex = /^\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{2})?$/;`

Comment: @Yass, WS is correct, you have to use the literal (`//`) syntax or double escape the slashes if you go with `new RegExp()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Why did you add non capture in decimal part ?

Comment: @noob: Since we are not interested in the submatches, why capture? Non-capturing groups are meant for grouping only, so   I used one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Any other motive than optimizing for speed and avoid wasting backreferences ?

Comment: Best practice, just a matter of habit. Style. Not really a big deal here.